# How to remove app id and name from pm2 logs?

Tags: json, node.js, pm2

Using a `pm2.json` configuration file, how do I remove **id | app.name |** prefix in my logs?

My example: **5 | api.bran |** part

[image]

I went through all `pm2 --help` and there's no info on how to do it. Is it even possible without editing pm2 module code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this post is  old, but i was looking for same options as i have to push the json logs to splunk and this is what i tried .

`pm2 logs --raw`

Comment: Wow, it does work. I don't know how did I overlook it before, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In short, **NO**

If you really need this, you can edit their [source](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/API/Log.js#L125) according to your need, should be simple enough.

**Update**: Seems like pm2 now offers [--raw flag](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/commit/678264519a174645534c0a13c1a6e44ba22242c3) for this purpose that for versions >= 2.5